# Delphi XE5 Android app running slow on Google Nexus 10

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

We are evaluating `Delphi XE5` specifically to see how easy it is to develop mobile apps. We have developed a simple Android app that scrolls through a TClientDataset using a DBNavigator. The application comprises a few input fields, labels and slider controls (TSwitch).

Everything works ok and sliders (animations) are responsive, except on a `Google Nexus 10` (Android 4.3) where everything happens in slow motion. It is like the app is still running in emulator mode. (A sliding button takes over 2 seconds to move from left to right!)

We have successfully tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.2) and a HTC One (4.2.2) and the UI is as responsive as one would expect.

**Update.**
We asked the question at Code Rage 8 and they are referring it to the R&D Department. Will update when or if we get an answer.

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert in Delphi(PASCAL should be banned :) ) but ... I think it because 2 resons: Nexus 10 resolution (2560 x 1600) and FireMonkey (Code generated from XE5 **DO NOT** USE NATIVE ANDROID CONTROLS - FireMonkey framework emulates 'em and by emulates i mean that this framework is using own code to draw all the controls)

Comment: That does not explain though why the app runs perfectly well on a Galaxy S3 and a HTC One.

Comment: @PietervanWyk The S3 has a 720 x 1280 pixels resolution. The Nexus 10 has more than 4 times more pixels! Since FireMonkey does the whole rendering by hand, it needs a lot more power to prepare the content. So I guess Selvin is right.

Comment: This sort of nonsense makes Emba's use the term *native* in their marketing of mobile tools look ridiculous. Clearly their tools have plus points, but they sure as hell are not native.

Answer (score 2):

I see mention of the screen resolution in comments. Has it actually been determined that it is the screen resolution that is the issue here?

Can you go into the developer options on the Nexus and try anything there that forces GPU usage or whatever might potentially help things along graphics-wise?

And is there anything clue-like in logcat? Run monitor.bat in the Android SDK tools directory or, if the path to it has spaces in, then that won't work so run ddms.bat instead from the same location (DDMS doesn't abort due to spaces in the path).

It would be good to get more evidence on the problem, rather than (educated) guesswork.

If it turns out to be screen size, well that will be interesting for Embo.